# Run command based on result of previous command (without failing the whole statement)

Tags: bash, shell-script

I would like to do something like this:

```
gatekeeper.sh && <script>
```

`gatekeeper.sh` determines whether <script> will be executed or not by returning either 0 or 1 depending on certain conditions - which works so far, but:

1. the whole command should fail (exit status != 0) if gatekeeper.sh succeeds but <script> doesn't
2. the whole command should **not** fail if gatekeeper.sh fails (and the second command is not executed)
3. <script> should not be altered

*If possible I would like to keep the syntax as short as possible for better readability*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If possible I would like to keep the syntax as short as possible for better readability

In this instance, I think that "as short as possible" ≠ "better readability". Even if I could think of a syntax `&&` and company that does what you want, I suspect it would be difficult to see at a glance what the author of the code intended.

I think this is a case where you want an extra statement for clarity:

```
if gatekeeper.sh; then
    <script>
fi
```

To some extent the most readable code is probably influenced by the business logic. What construct translates that logical intent into code most transparently?

Answer (score 0):

Putting my approach up for discussion. I am aware that [*eval* is *evil* (sometimes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead) but I trust the commands being executed.

**gatekeeper.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

if [[ <condition> ]]; then
    eval "$1"
    exit "$?"
fi
```

Usage: `gatekeeper.sh "<command>"`

Comment: gatekeeper.sh is what is being tested. OP is looking for bash syntax to evaluate based on the result of gatekeeper.sh.

Comment: My solution works for me - the OP - I've updated the description a little bit hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Oh, I didn't even notice that you were OP. Your question implies that gatekeeper.sh should not be modified.

Comment: only the script that runs (or doesn't - based on gatekeeper.sh) shouldn't be altered

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the exit status of the `gatekeeper.sh` in a variable and use it later in an `exit` (or `return` if it's a function rather than a script)

```
#!/bin/sh
gatekeeper.sh
status=$?
[ "$status" != 0 ] && <script>
exit "$status"
```